# Think my Dad may have just downloaded the Apple Security Malware

Tags: imac, security, malware, virus, javascript

My dad doesn't use a Virus checker (doesnt disable Java either and isn't running the latest OSX) and just appears to have fallen for the Apple Security malware popup (looked and sounded something like this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7861498) tried to save him over the phone - did a force quit, he restarted Safari, it now had a timer, he got in a panic and clicked scan now (& I am not 100% what happened next as he hung up to do whatever he did).

I called him back and got him to switch it off and Pull the internet cable out of the back and switch off which may have partly saved him. I am expecting given the time taken it has downloaded whatever payload it may have been hiding. Have a screenshot but not sure how to post it from my phone - looked like the one in the thread.

Any idea what it is and how to remove it? Thinking about it I don't think he would have put his password in so I am thinking what it downloaded was probably just malware and unlikely to have been an App?

I live a couple of miles away so will go and try and help them tomorrow - just want to have an idea of what I am dealing with.

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestions.

Comment: Is he an admin and did he type his password if/when he was prompted when the malware was installing?

Comment: Don't know to be honest. He would have admin rights. My parents share the computer. I don't think he would have been that stupid but wouldn't want to rule it out.

Comment: If your folks' computer has TM set up, you could wipe the HD and restore from a pre-infection backup.

Comment: TBH most Mac male ware is not harmful just annoying. My suggest is to run a Malwarebytes scan and check safari extensions and that’s it. He most likely started an online “scan” (on Safari) that is fake and doesn’t actually scan anything,

Comment: I have seen people with 50,000+ instances of malware and non were harmful just slowed down and random pop ups.

Comment: More than likely, you can just create a new profile (try that first) as the damage is probably contained there.  If the new profile has no symptoms of  malware, just copy his files over.  If it does...we'll have to look at other remedies.

Comment: @Allan Instead of copying files you can just change the permissions and create an alias.

Comment: @David thanks - good idea but unfortunately they don't have TM 

Comment: @JBis so effectively partition the problem under a different profile? Could see the Malwarebytes route as well but would be just a touch wary about having to do anything with the Admin password.

Comment: @user8812 Malwarebytes is recommended by Apple. It requires admin password to install. But it is safe. Honestly, I think creating a new user is a bit of avoiding the problem not fixing it. I wouldn’t recommend doing that. If your dad forgets and logs in to the old account....

Comment: @user8812 Also, teach your dad a bit about phishing attempts. **#1 thing: No one tells you that there’s a problem with your computer.** Same way no one comes to your door a goes “Hi I am official Kohler support and we have detected your toilet is clogged. Let me come into your house and fix it. I promise not to steal all the jewelry in your house.” If your toilet is clogged **you** would call a plumber. If your computer is broken **you** call tech support.

Comment: @JBis bare in mind when he restarted Safari I was at the other end of a phone and he told me he had a 90 second timer - before it said that his hard drive would suffer potentially terminal damage. By the time he told me he had about 60 seconds left and I couldn't think quickly enough (couldn't remember if he had his internet wired in or over wifi). Should have just told him to pull the plug

Comment: @user8812 No reason to pull plug. You probably would do more damage. All those things are on the internet and are fake. Again run MWB and you’ll be fine.

Comment: @JBis think I could probably download AVG for free as well (from memory it's free for Mac - I'm a long term Intego customer). As I said though until we know what's going on with it - I'd just be a bit mindful of using the Admin password on anything (e.g to install something).

Comment: @user8812 AVG is good too. MWB is also free. But to install just about anything (good or bad) your going to need to input your admin password.

Comment: @JBis think I resolved it here - looks like it was Mac Cleaner which thankfully didn't get installed https://discussions.apple.com/message/33577079?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Glad you could find your answer but please don’t cross post

Comment: @JBis understood - just wanted to try and round this out. From the Etre Check it just looked like the only thing it pulled was the AVG which I had installed.